# Lenses don't show up in the Dash

Tags: 11.10, unity, lenses

I have Ubuntu 11.10 (Oct, 2011).

I never use Unity-2d.

I downloaded various Lenses from the Software Center. 
Then I restarted the system.

But I don't see any differences! What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lenses need to be stored in /usr/share/unity/lenses. Open that folder and you'll see that each lens is stored in it's own folder. At a minimum there will be a {lens name}.lens file. You will probably need to log out and log back in for the new lens to be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Some lenses doesn't show up in Dash. For example, if you install the Calculator Lense, it will only appear if you type for example "2 * 3" on the search box. Some have "tabs" bellow the Dash. Just click on them and them you can make your search.

Comment: Yes, I now that. For example I download, like others Lense, the Calculator Lense and when I type in the dash "2 * 3" or things like that, I wait and wait and wait but nothing appears! The Lenses don't work!! Were I can install the Lense? Those that are available in the Software Center I installed and didn't work.

Comment: Try to use alt + f2 and write "unity --replace"